# fail to use session in php

Tags: php, security, session

I read a bit on how to secure a session and what I decided to do was to save the session_id to the database, and then save it to a session variable after it has been encrypted.

Here is the class that I used for the encryption (it was writen by Orielly books author):

[Encrypted class using session_set_save_handler](https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-Secure-Session/blob/master/SecureSession.php)

The I apply it this way:

```
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',true);       

//calls the session class.  
 require_once(dirname(__file__)."/../../Administrator/secure_session.php");
             session_start();

            if( !isset($_SESSION['mod']) )          
            {   
                Moderator::insert_moderator($name,session_id());    

                $_SESSION['mod']= session_id();

                $_SESSION['time']=time();

                echo "<br/>Moderator session: ".$_SESSION['mod'];
            }
```

This is the exception which is being thrown:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'I cannot generate a secure pseudo-random key. Please use PHP >= 5.3 or Mcrypt extension' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Administrator\secure_session.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Administrator\secure_session.php(107): SecureSession->_randomKey(32) #1 [internal function]: SecureSession->open('C:\xampp\htdocs...', 'PHPSESSID') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\headerSite.php(43): session_start() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\mainHome.php(14): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Administrator\secure_session.php on line 74

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this, cause I dont understand much of encryption!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is because you're probably using PHP < 5.3 or you didn't include the mcrypt extension in your php.ini

In your error log says line 74 of the class, if you look at it:

```
(71)    if (defined(MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)) {
(72)        return mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
(73)    } else {
(74)       throw new Exception("I cannot generate a secure pseudo-random key. Please use PHP >= 5.3 or Mcrypt extension");
(75)    }
```

that means that MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM is not defined, and if you look in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) you'll see that it was introduced in PHP >= 5.3 on Widnows platforms

---

To update you PHP download the latest stable version from [here](http://php.net/downloads.php#v5) or [here](http://windows.php.net/download/) (Windows)

Comment: How can I update my php... I have got this link to type to download and install the extension: http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=26527

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd I edited my answer with the links to download PHP

Comment: libmcrypt-win32-- I got that library. How can I cooperate that extention so that it wont throw that exception?

Comment: Okay, I am downloading your link..Do I need to press the install and simply install it like a dummy to update the php..or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd the mcrypt extension is included in the latest versions of PHP, just download them and you will see in the ext folder the php_mcrypt exntesion

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd the windows installer does everything to configure PHP.

Comment: How many times do I need to call that class, every time I start the session or will one time be enough!!?

Comment: I got an error saying : Error trying to access httpd.config file. You will need manually to configure your web server.. I am using xamp.. How do I update this thing correctly?

Comment: You'll need to update the httpd.conf manually it's located in xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and add what you see in the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/eRmfWHzn

Comment: should I drop those lines into my php..and change 5_2 to 5_3?

Comment: Those lines should go on your httpd.conf as I explained in the previous comment.. don't change anything, unless your php path is different from C:\PHP. When you open the httpd.conf file you will already see those lines (From the previous PHP installation)

Comment: Actually, I dont see them. What I was, I told the installer not to install a webserver, cause I have xamp already, which is located in C:\xamp  and the location of the installation is c:\programFile\php

Comment: I think you want me to overrite the php folder in xamp..which I am going to do know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5017/discussion-between-dmitry-makovetskiyd-and-serpro)

Answer (score 0):

If you get this message and you have `PHP 5.3` or later. You have not enabled the `OpenSSL` extention in your `php.ini` file .

What you need to do is to have the following line in your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I assume that you are using windows, other wise change the extention accordingly