# updating php to 5.3 not working

Tags: php, security, session

I get this error when using some library called: Mcrypt extension:

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'I cannot generate a secure 
    pseudo-random key. Please use PHP >= 5.3 or Mcrypt extension' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Administrator\secure_session.php:74 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Administrator\secure_session.php(107): SecureSession->_randomKey(32) 
#1 [internal function]: SecureSession->open('C:\xampp\htdocs...', 'PHPSESSID') 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\User\User\headerSite.php(31): session_start() 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\mainHome.php(14): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\Administrator\secure_session.php on line 74
```

I found the class in this link:

[secure session](https://github.com/ezimuel/PHP-Secure-Session/blob/master/SecureSession.php)

I dont understand what version of php do I have!?!? and why hasnt the php updated, I have only updated my xamp to the newest version right now..

Note: there is no mistake in the class as it was made by one of Oreilly books' author and was used and recommended by a few people in here.

Comment: Modify your php.ini, add "extension=php_mcrypt.dll" (you may have to modify the path), and restart apache.  XAMPP 1.7.7 includes PHP 5.3.8, but perhaps the error message is misleading in suggesting that PHP 5.3 will solve your problem.

Comment: note that XAMPP will not auto-update anything for you, you have to reinstall with a newer version if you want to update your PHP/mySQL etc.

Comment: `phpversion()` will tell you what you're running.

Comment: It's possible that your script requires PHP 5.3 to have been compiled with certain flags that XAMPP omitted when they built your binary.  Your best bet is to just install the mcrypt extension.

Comment: That's gotta be a nice, sentient, self-aware library, talking about itself in the first person.

Comment: I installed it, it installs it outside the xamp directory :(.. not working.. True Radu, cause it was authored by someone who is an author of some programming book

Comment: dammit, I want this code to work !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your php version on the command line using: `php -v`

You can find out your php version, loaded extensions, and just about everything about PHP by putting the following in a file and calling it from your web browser:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Of course, don't leave that up on your production server.

As for the error, you need to find your php.ini, which will be at `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and uncomment or add the line `extension=php_mcrpyt.dll`

You might want to have a peek in `C:\xampp\php\extensions\` and make sure that dll actually exists. If not (and you have verified you do have PHP 5.3) you can [go download the "Zip" version of the windows installer](http://windows.php.net/download/) which matches your version, unzip it, and then simply copy that file to your extensions.

**EDIT:**

I had a look at the [php manual for mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php) and found this: "mcrypt is built in for PHP 5.3.x on windows, you don't need to do anything with a dll anymore."; I think it's entirely possible that you upgraded PHP to a different directory than your XAMPP install; check those versions (http://localhost should take you to the xampp panel where you can find phpinfo() in the sidebar)

Comment: Here is a similar thread on SO to your problem, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138213/fail-to-use-session-in-php

Comment: i tried your solution , now , I am going to download the zip, but know that I have no extensions director

Comment: VC9 x86 Thread Safe (2011-Aug-23 12:01:10)

Installer  <--- I am downloading that..

Comment: Okay, it looks like you may want to put them in C:\xampp\php\ext\ directory; if it doesn't exist you can copy it straight from the zip download. I'd be surprised if xampp doesn't have this though; I've never had a problem with it missing extensions before!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5029/discussion-between-kato-and-dmitry-makovetskiyd)

Answer (score 1):

If you get this message and you have PHP 5.3 or later. You have not in your php.ini file enabled the OpenSSL extension.

What you need to do is to have the following line in your php.ini file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I asume that you are using windows, other wise change the extension accordingly